# Objective C - Custom segue called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm using a custom segue code that I have from the net.

But everytime I'm using it, the viewDidLoad of the destination controller is called twice!

I'm using this code becuase it's like a fake "push" back & forward animation (I don't want to use the original "push" segue).

What is wrong with this code?

Following is my code:
**.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCustomSeguePushForward : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
```

**.m file**

```
#import "MyCustomSeguePushForward.h"

@implementation MyCustomSeguePushForward

-(void) perform
{
UIView *preV = ((UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController).view;
UIView *newV = ((UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController).view;

UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
newV.center = CGPointMake(preV.center.x + preV.frame.size.width, newV.center.y);
[window insertSubview:newV aboveSubview:preV];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                 animations:^{
                     newV.center = CGPointMake(preV.center.x, newV.center.y);
                     preV.center = CGPointMake(0- preV.center.x, newV.center.y);}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [preV removeFromSuperview];
                     window.rootViewController = self.destinationViewController;
                 }];
}



@end
```

**Implement**

```
ProfilePicturesCollectionView *Pictures = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Picture"];
MyCustomSeguePushForward *segue = [[MyCustomSeguePushForward alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"CustomSeguePushForward" source:self destination:Pictures];
[segue perform];
```

Comment: Can you plz share calling code ?/

Comment: In which event this code is called ? 'viewDidLoad' e.g

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your question.
every time I'm using this code, it's like called the destenation controller twice (and all the methods inside the destenation controller called twice also).

Comment: Taking view from viewController and inserting it in another view is totaly wrong.

Comment: So, what should I do?